# Vyatta Nat Rule Help Translating From Cisco ASA Rule

Tags: cisco, nat, vyatta

I'm fairly new to Vyatta and need advice on how to translate the following rule example from a Cisco ASA to the Vyatta.

```
static (dmz2,outside) 192.168.254.0 192.168.254.0 netmask/24
```

How do I create this NAT rule on the Vyatta?